# How to identify a value from a comma-separated list in a particular column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column (let's say `Email`) and it contains a few email ids in a comma-separated format (`abcd@gmail.com,pqrst@yahoo.co.in,mnop@outlook.com`).

Now my query should search on this column whether a given email id is present in this column.

Currently I am checking by converting in to xml.

```
SELECT @EmailIds = EmailId 
FROM Tablename 
WHERE email= @emailid                   

SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@EmailIds,@Split,'</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')
```

Any better and efficient way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So? Where's the question?

Comment: Why don't use a `xml` column to store the e-mails in the first place, for example? Or a child table? Comma separated values are a bad idea in terms of DB performance (and the handling is wonky).

Comment: xml data type as few [limitations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Agree with @Luaan, I've had my dealings with "devs" trying to be smart (read lazy) and put comma delimited strings in columns. Updating that data is both tedious and eats unneccesary resources since it will likely result in having UDFs taking care of some of the work. XQuery can extract the data quite easily but in a relaional database perspective it really should be stored in a separate table

Comment: Yes, the xml data type does have limitations. Which of those concern you? Storing comma separated values in a varchar column has tons of limitations of its own. And in fact, storing the data in a separate table also has limitations. Software development is a lot about picking the optimal approach, not the perfect approach (which doesn't really exist).

Comment: The **proper way** to do this would be to obey to the **first normal form** of database design and put your e-mail addresses into a **separate child table** that references your table here. That way, you **avoid** messy comma-separated lists, and you have a nice, proper relational model and checking for existence of an e-mail becomes a breeze.....

Answer (score 1):

I'm maybe a bit out of line here but for just searching for an email in a comma-separated column, wouldnt a like command do the trick?

```
select Email from Tablename
where Email LIKE '%,' + @emailid + ',%'
or Email like  @emailid + ',%'
or Email like '%,' +  @emailid
```

Comment: Yup, it would. However, it also cannot use an index, and updating the column is rather tricky. But those are both an issue in the OP's way too, so why not...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a function for example :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromCommaSeparated]
(

  @StringInput VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @tmp TABLE ( Id VARCHAR(500))
AS 
BEGIN


    DECLARE @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] VARCHAR(MAX) )

    DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @String = LEFT(@StringInput,
                               ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput)
                                             - 1, -1), LEN(@StringInput)))
            SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                         ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',',
                                                          @StringInput), 0),
                                                LEN(@StringInput)) + 1,
                                         LEN(@StringInput))
            INSERT  INTO @tmp
                    ( Id )
            VALUES  ( @String )
        END
    RETURN

END



SELECT EmailId 
FROM Tablename 
WHERE email IN (
                  SELECT    *
                  FROM      dbo.GetTableFromCommaSeparated(@emailid) )
                )
```